# Get image of table cell from sqlite database in Xcode

Tags: xcode, image, sqlite, cell

I have a table view in my app and would like have a left-side-image for every cell. This image should come from an sqlite database. What code would I need to use for this?

Answer (score 0):

you should review [fmdb](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb). check the `main.m` file for an example of storing and reading an image file.